# Is it possible to move tomcat's work/Catalina/localhost/ directory?

Tags: tomcat

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow change the path of Tomcat `work/Catalina/localhost/` directory?

Lets assume I have two users: `tomcat_install_user` and `tomcat_run_user`. 
I would like to store all tomcat installation and configuration files on tomcat_install_user and to use `tomcat_run_user` only for running Tomcat process. I would like `tomcat_run_user` to have only read privileges to the other user files.

But Tomcat needs to create work directory in `$CATALINA_BASE`. I wouldn't like to move the whole `$CATALINA_BASE` to `tomcat_run_user`, just the `work` directory. Is it even possible? How to point Tomcat to this directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [standard Host implementation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) of Tomcat supports the attribute `workDir` in the `<Host>` element in the `server.xml` config file.

> Pathname to a scratch directory to be used by applications for this Host. Each application will have its own sub directory with temporary read-write use. Configuring a Context workDir will override use of the Host workDir configuration. This directory will be made visible to servlets in the web application by a servlet context attribute (of type java.io.File) named javax.servlet.context.tempdir as described in the Servlet Specification. If not specified, a suitable directory underneath $CATALINA_BASE/work will be provided.

You can set it to a directory of your choice, for example

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" 
    workDir="/home/tomcat_run_user/other_work_dir">

....

</Host>
```

Note also that [standard Context implementation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation) also offers the attribute `workDir` which overrides the setting in the `<Host>` element, but only for the application specifying one.

Comment: Would it also work fine to replace the default directory with a symlink to another volume?